# create perl script to connect remotely to another server and read File?

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, remote-server

I am new  to perl programming also to networking .
My Task is to connect to remote server and read file from server using Perl script.I know how to read file from local machine but not how to read from remote server?

```
Code to read file from local machine but not know how to connect to remote server and read file?

#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, 'C:\Users\saqib riaz\Desktop\saqi\properties.txt');

while(<FH>)
{
    "$_";
}   
close(FH);
```

I am using window operating system And strawberry with padre ide latest version

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me with Strawberry Perl version 5.30. It uses [`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) and prints a file `file.txt` on the server:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;

my $host = 'my.host.com';
my $user = 'user_name';
my $password = 'xxxxxxx';
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect($host) or $ssh2->die_with_error;
$ssh2->check_hostkey('ask') or $ssh2->die_with_error;
$ssh2->auth_password($user, $password);
my $chan = $ssh2->channel() or $ssh2->die_with_error;
$chan->exec('cat file.txt') or $ssh2->die_with_error;
print while <$chan>;
$chan->close;
```

Note: `Net::SSH2` comes preinstalled with Strawberry Perl so no need to install it.

Note: I also tried [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) but could not get it to work.

Comment: Unable to connect to remote host .showing error at line no 9.                                                    With ide"die_with_error is not a valid Net::SSH2 macro at script.pl line 9"

Comment: Try to enable debugging output with `$ssh2->debug(1)`. Do you get some more information about the error?

Comment: invalid argument  <-1 LIBSSH2_error_socket_none> at script.pl line 9

Comment: @saqibriaz Have you modified the script that I posted? Is it exactly the same except for the password, username and host?

Comment: @saqibriaz that means you are using a very old version of `Net::SSH2`. Upgrade it!

Comment: @HåkonHægland `Net::OpenSSH` does not work on Windows.

Comment: @salva Thanks for the information, the strange thing was that it installed fine with `cpanm` but when I used it from a script `my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);` the whole script aborted but no error messages was shown, it just returned to the CMD prompt not executing any more lines from the script

Comment: @HåkonHægland it is installable on Windows because there are parts of the module that are usable on Windows (those relating to command quoting), but the main SSH functionality does not work due to missing features on the OpenSSH port to Windows.

Comment: @saqibriaz Have you more than one Perl installation on your machine?

Comment: @saqibriaz you may be still using an old version of the module. Add `print "$Net::SSH2::VERSION\n";` at the beginning of your script, after the `use` statments.

Comment: @HåkonHægland No.I only install Strawberry perl.

Comment: @saqibriaz Also show the output of `perl -MNet::SSH2 -E"say $INC{'Net/SSH2.pm'}"` and `perl --version`

Comment: @HåkonHægland This is perl 5 version 30.

Comment: @HåkonHægland  SSH server may be not running properly that can be issue?

Comment: @saqibriaz Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Window 8.1

Comment: @saqibriaz I am using Windows 10, could you also try on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks a Lot for your precious time.

Comment: I will try that on window 10.

Comment: @HåkonHægland can we use"use Net::Telnet" instead of "use Net::SSH2".

Comment: @HåkonHægland what should be the" @host" here?